# How to print the next line in Python with text extracted using pdfplumber

Tags: python, pdfplumber

How can I print the next line from the text that I extracted from a PDF using
pdfPlumber extract.text function?

I have tried line.next() but it does not work.

The actual job name is on the line after the "Job Name". As per example below.

Job Name

Albany Mall Development

My code as per below.

```
jobName_re = re.compile(r'(Job Name)')
siteAddress_re = re.compile(r'(Wellington\s)(.+)')
file = 'invoices.pdf'

lines = []

with pdfplumber.open(file) as myPdf:
    for page in myPdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            jobName = jobName_re.search(line)
            siteAddress = siteAddress_re.search(line)
            if jobName:
                print('The next line that follows Job Name is', line.next())
            elif siteAddress:
                print(siteAddress.group(1))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the next line"? Could you show an example of *exactly* what text you get, and *exactly* what output you want to produce, and explain how that differs from your existing output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

### Option 1

You could switch to using an integer index to loop through the records:

```
lines = text.split('\n')
for i in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
```

Then you can access `lines[i+1]`.

### Option 2

Set a flag to say you've seen the heading for job name, then pick it up next time round the loop. Something like this:

```
        last_was_job_heading = False
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            siteAddress = siteAddress_re.search(line)
            if last_was_job_heading:
                print('The next line that follows Job Name is', line)
            elif siteAddress:
                print(siteAddress.group(1))
            last_was_job_heading = jobName_re.search(line)
```

### Option 3

Don't split the text into lines at all. Instead use smarter regular expressions to parse multiple lines at once.

### Option 4

Use a parsing library of some sort instead of regular expressions. That's probably overkill in this simple case.

Comment: Thank you so much Mattew. The first option works for me. I was able to print the line after the Job Name line.